# ModalView in Kivy

Tags: python, background, kivy, kivymd, modal-view

I'm having trouble with Kivy. I'm using a ModalView and I want the background color to be white or the same as the app's main theme. The documentation says: "This acts as a multiplier to the texture color. The default texture is gray, so just setting the background color will give a darker result. To set a plain color, set the background_normal to ''.". But I can't figure out how and where to specify this value. Please tell me how to make the background of ModalView be white or like the main theme.

Tried like this:

`view = ModalView(size_hint=(.9, .9), background_normal='.') view.add_widget(Content()) view.open()`
Got it:

`TypeError: Properties ['background_normal'] passed to __init__ may not be existing property names.`

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

To make the ModalView background, for example, white, you need to find an image of a white background (or any other color) and write background = 'PATH' in the ModalView:

```
view = ModalView(size_hint=(.9, .9), background='PATH') 
view.add_widget(Content())
view.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

In spite of what the documentation says, I have found this way to set the background color of a `ModalView`:

```
    view = ModalView(size_hint=(.9, .9), background='', overlay_color=[1, 1, 1, 1])
    view.add_widget(Content())
    view.open()
```